# Existing App: upgrade from iOS 4.2 to iOS 5.0

Tags: ios5, ios4, armv7, armv6

I rewrote an app I have on the iTunes store using iOS5.

- The original app had support for armv6 and armv7 on iOS 4.2 and higher.
- The new app has only support for armv7 on iOS5.0 and higher (since iOS5 API is only supported on armv7)

So there's the issue. iTunes won't let me upgrade the app because it would mean some users won't be able to get an upgrade. Error message:

> This bundle is invalid. `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in the `Info.plist` may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions.

The value in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` is armv7. armv7 is required b/c iOS5 api.

What do I do? Do I pull the old app and replace it with the new one? What about my customers? How will they be able to upgrade? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I also found this in my search:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html

I wish they would fix this. I mean we can't support all versions all the time if they want us to use new features, and I'm not going to rerelease the app every time they upgrade the OS.

Answer (score 0):

In short: `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` cannot be changed in app updates.

Take a look at [Ole Begemann's post](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/) explaining it and suggesting changing required SDK version as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same issue. I tried adding armv6 to my architectures but that didn't work.

To make it work, I changed the deployment target to 5.0 and viola, no problems :)