# Upgrading app from iOS 5 to iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, upgrade

We are submitting an app to the app store and trying to figure out if we should submit for iOS 5.0 or iOS 6.x.

Last time when we tried to upgrade an app from iOS 4.3 to 5.0, it wouldn't let us, since some users wouldn't be able to get the upgrade. (I can't remember the exact message, [but it could have been this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338569/existing-app-upgrade-from-ios-4-2-to-ios-5-0), a difference in hardware).

I was just wondering if we submit for iOS 5.0 now, will be have to submit a new app with new bundle name if we want to use features in iOS 6.x later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if we submit for iOS 5.0 now, will be have to submit a new app with new bundle name if we want to use features in iOS 6.x later.

No, you will not need change app or bundle name if a future release of your app requires iOS 6. You will simply need to change the Deployment SDK in your app info.plist and everything will be ok. Of course, users still on iOS5 will not be allowed to upgrade to your latest iOS6-only version and will stick to the one they already have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has decided to drop support for old devices running armv6 which is now deprecated. All armv7 devices can be upgraded to iOS 5, so it´s good to set that as the minimum version supported. There are a lot of benefits with using iOS 5 as ARC and Storyboards etc.
The users that couldn´t upgrade from iOS 4.2 where using armv6 devices and are thus no longer supported by Apple.
You can always update later to iOS 6 when most of your user have upgraded to the version.